# join on vs where-SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Hi could you please let me know which one is more optimized:

```
select a.*,b.* from a join b on a.id=b.id and a.name='test';

select a.*,b.* from a join b on a.id=b.id where a.name='test';
```

Thanks

Comment: In this case both queries should work the same.

Comment: Compare the execution plans and you will know.

Comment: In this case the same, however when working with left or right joins the will be a big diff. Albin is right, check the execution plan and learn....

Comment: Ineterestingly I ran this 1000 times for each and WHERE comes out about 25% faster - I am guessing it is something to do with the internal MySQL order of operations (as the execution plan is the same). Nice interesting question - quite suprised by results!

Comment: The MySQL engine is screwy on a good day...

Comment: I'm not really an expert buy from my point of view the second query should work faster on big datasets. It's much easier to join fewer data then more that(obvious). WHERE does the filtering and then the join is applied. Corect me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Interesting! Actually I thought the first query would be faster, because it joins a fewer rows (only those rows which have a.name='test' and a.id=b.id), whereas the second one joins more rows (only those rows where a.id=b.id) and then it filters them based on the where clause! Apparently I'm wrong!

Comment: Filtering in ON vs. WHERE is just a logical difference (for Inner Joins), so if then optimizer is not totally stupid it should produce exactly the same plan for both queries.

Comment: if you want to optimize you would never use select * when you havea join as you are returning the join field(s) twice. Of course, I happen to agree with the folks who consider select * to be an antipattern and it should not be used in production queries at all ever.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion with good syntax, it is easier to read a query if instead of those 'AND's there is a series of WHERE clauses after.

Since you're using an inner join there is no difference between the two. The inner join shows only where there is an exact match on your join.

If you were to use a left join though, things would get a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

In the most simple case, both are equivalent. To prove, you can just look at both execution plans

```
explain select a.*,b.* from a join b on a.id=b.id and a.name='test'
```

gives

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+  
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |  
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+  
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where                    |  
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using join buffer |  
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+  
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and then for

```
explain select a.*,b.* from a join b on a.id=b.id where a.name='test'
```

gives also

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See also [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1f461/1)

Comment: I'm not surprised, because the manual chapter [How MySQL Optimizes WHERE Clauses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/where-optimizations.html) states: _For each table in a join, a simpler WHERE is constructed to get a fast WHERE evaluation for the table and also to skip rows as soon as possible._